# How do I make a live USB on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver)?

Tags: live-usb, mkusb

I have tried everything, and it just trous put errors. How can I fix it?

Comment: Also: UEFI only USB key, just extract ISO ( 7 zip or similar) to FAT32 formatted flash drive partition & set boot flag.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media
 and: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb or 
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager/iso2usb

Comment: It could also be great that you give more details on what you have tried. "I have tried everything" sounds a bit vague :)

Answer (score 0):

This is quite easy, you can use the `dd` command in the terminal.

`dd` is used to create exact copies of files/partitions/drives into another file/partition/drive, for example:

You could create a backup (copy) of an entire drive into a file called *sda.backup* with the next command

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=sda.backup
```

But in your case, you should do the opposite, restore the image (OS-Name.iso) into a drive (the USB flash drive), to do so you should use a command like this one:

```
sudo dd if=/path/to/the/image/OS.iso of=/dev/sdX
```

The *X* means the letter of the drive, you can find out with the next command (although it's usually *b*):

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also add `status=progress` since it takes a while to copy the iso

```
sudo dd if=file.iso of=/dev/<usb drive> status=progress
```

if you dont know where is your usb drive, use the `lsblk` command in terminal